# Can we have multiple Postgres XL cluster on the same system?

Tags: postgresql, database-cluster, postgres-xl

Whenever we create a Postgres XL cluster, the coordinators, datanodes and GTMs are identical to the same cluster isn't it? So is it possible to create another cluster on the same host using pgxc_ctl? Do I have to generate a different cluster configuration file so that the new cluster is totally independent to the older one? Please put some light into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You must run components on non-conflicting resources such as data directories and ports and also use a separate pgxc_ctl.conf file to identify each cluster. You may use -c options of pgxc_ctl to specify a non-default config file location.